# Objective-C: Question about NSString and scope

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, scope

I have a global NSString variable that I declared in my ViewController.m file, outside of any methods, but not in my .h file.

```
NSString *menuString;
```

It is initialized inside `webViewDidFinishLoad` and it works when I do this

```
NSString *menu = [self getParameter:url :@"Menu"];
menuString = [menu copy];
```

but not when I do this

```
NSString *menu = [self getParameter:url :@"Menu"];
menuString = menu;
```

or

```
menuString = [self getParameter:url :@"Menu"];
```

Here, by "it works" I mean the value is saved and I can use it in other methods. Otherwise, during debug, it says that menuString is out of scope. I was wondering why it behaves differently depending on the initialization.

(getParameter is just a method that takes two strings and returns a string).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `getParameter:` returns an autoreleased `NSString` object.

That means that this object will be automatically released at the end of that run loop (when the autorelease pool is drained).

Because you never retained that object, once it's autoreleased it's dealloced and you can't use it anymore.

By doing a `copy`, you are creating a retained copy of that object that won't be autoreleased at the end of the run loop.
It would also work if you used `retain`:

```
menuString = [[self getParameter:url :@"Menu"] retain];
```

note that if you `copy` or `retain` it, you have to release it later at some point when you don't need it anymore, otherwise you'll have a memory leak.

Comment: Are all method returned objects autoreleased?

Comment: basically any method that is not named `alloc` or `copy` (or variations of those, like `allocWithZone` or `mutableCopy`) that returns an object, should return an autoreleased object. Take a look at this guide for more info: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MemoryManagement.html

Answer (score 1):

`[self getParameter:url :@"Menu"];` returns an `autoreleased` string object. This means during the next cycle of the Autorelease Pool it will be released. If nothing else has increased its retain count (`retain` or `copy` call), it will be dealloc'd. Once it's dealloc'd and you attempt to use it you will crash.

Your first example, you copy the string you now have an object that will not be cleaned up when the Autorelease Pool cleans up.

However, make sure you `release` the object in your class's `dealloc` method to prevent an leaks.